# associating files with same MIME but different file extensions to differentt applications

Tags: gnome, file-format, mime-type, file-association

How can I associate files with same MIME but different extensions to different applications.
For example both `.maff` & `.zip` files have `application/zip` MIME ; But I need to open `.maff` by `Firefox` and `.zip` by `ArchiveManager`
Setting this via `Open with` dialog associates application to MIME that causes both files open with same application.
How can I configure this in Gnome?
I'm using Ubuntu Lucid Lynx.

Thanks

Comment: I posted my step-by-step solution here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12505072#2

Answer (score 4):

I strove to make **Firefox** ⟷ **maff** association only for one user (me). So I didn't touch files under `/etc`.

I did the following:

1. Restore correct association between ZIP-files and archive manager (I did it within default file manager **Nemo**).
2. Create definition of MIME type. In my case I created `firefox-maff-my.xml` file in `~/.local/share/mime/packages` directory with the content provided below:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
     <mime-type type="application/maff">
            <comment>Mozilla Archive Format</comment>
            <glob pattern="*.maff"/>
     </mime-type>
   </mime-info>
   ```
3. Update MIME database

   ```
   update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime/
   ```
4. Edit `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. 
   Add

   ```
   application/maff=firefox.desktop
   ```

   line right under `[Default Applications]`.
5. Log out, then log in.

In case of doubts you can make backup of each involved file before editing it. If something will go wrong you can revert everything you did (just restore original files, remove `firefox-maff-my.xml` and run `update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime/` again).

---

<sub>I've faced similar issue in Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon. Perhaps this also will work for GNOME (because both follow freedesktop.org).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

As of 2016/Feb/20, this is the correct solution to associate MAFF files to Firefox (or any other files), without affecting the Compressed archive/ZIP association:

```
# run as sudo

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
<mime-type type="application/x-maff">
<comment>Maff File</comment>
<glob pattern="*.maff"/>
</mime-type>
</mime-info>' > /usr/share/mime/packages/maff.xml

update-mime-database /usr/share/mime

# now kill X or logout.
```

The `assogiate` solution is not valid anymore, as the package has been removed from the Ubuntu repositories after v14.04.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick on 14.04! After following your instructions I just had to "Open with other application..." once to associate a MAFF file with Firefox. After that step, all MAFF files now open with Firefox on double-click, and plain zip files still open with my archive manager.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a `.maff` file is exactly, but you need to define a new MIME type for it. Application associations are based on MIME type and not file extension.

Comment: `.maff` is the "Mozilla Archive Format" that is used by a [firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozilla-archive-format) that actually is a `zip` file like `.jar` files; How should I define a MIME for that?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do this is by using `mimeopen` command to open .maff file format using Firefox

Open terminal and type

```
mimeopen some_file_name.maff
```

You will be provided with available packages to open the .maff file

```
Please choose a default application for files of type application/zip

    1) Archive Manager  (file-roller)
    2) Archive Mounter  (mount-archive)
    3) Other...
```

select 3 from the option and enter the command as `firefox`

```
use application #3
use command: firefox
```

This will open up .maff file in Firefox and will be set as default program to open .maff file

Comment: #1: This only sets default application for `mimeopen` and not nautilus! #2 this still only relys on mime type so setting default application for `.maff` will sets that application for `.zip` too!!! (I tried and it did)