# How can I associate MAFF file format with firefox

Tags: firefox, 14.10, archive

I have been saving web pages in MAFF fromat but in ubuntu these files are associated with fileroller. How can I change this so that it always opens with firefox?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [associating files with same MIME but different file extensions to differentt applications](http://askubuntu.com/questions/226607/associating-files-with-same-mime-but-different-file-extensions-to-differentt-app)

Answer (score 0):

Simply right click a .maff file >select open with> Select Other Applications> Find and select firefox.

Unless you want to convert the file you cant do that, if you do want to convert it visit here: http://en.pdf24.org/maff-2-pdf.html  *I take no responsibility if this program is unsafe.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, this opens it, but it is still a file roller file. if I double click it it opens fireroller. How can I change it so that double clicking the file opens it in firefox?

Comment: Unless you want to convert the file you cant do that, if you do want to convert it visit here: http://en.pdf24.org/maff-2-pdf.html  *I take no responsibility if this program is unsafe.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't want to convert. You can change this through the files properties dialog, but this then opens all zip files in firefox. I can't believe there is no option to do this... everything is suppossed to be better in linux but this simple thing can't be done, although windows can do it for decades. I can't believe no one needs to ever do this????

Comment: Then I dont think you can