# How to set default application based on file extension, not mime type?

Tags: default-programs, file-format, mime-type

I have files with extensions .txt, .sln and .csproj, they all have mime type text/plain. But they should be opened by different programs. .txt - by Vim, .sln and .csproj - by Rider. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Here https://askubuntu.com/a/736954/976481 is explained how to create custom MIME type based on the file extension. I had to change their solution as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
    <mime-type type="text/solution">
       <comment>Rider solution file</comment>
       <glob pattern="*.sln"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

And add this file as rider.xml to /usr/share/mime/packages.

It works but still looks like a hack. Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: Usually such changes are made for single user in `~/.local/share/mime/packages/`. Check the docs in /usr/share/doc/shared-mime-info/shared-mime-info-spec.pdf . Not sure about exact util name, but `xdg-mime` may help.

Comment: @N0rbert thanks for the suggestion, I've moved the files there by hand.